# Block an interface to be extended

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

As since in a class  I can do:

```
public final class Foo{}
```

wich means no more classes can extends that `Foo` class... e.g. `String` class is final, so no custom class can extends the class `String`.

How can I prevent to do the same  with an interface?

If I do

```
public interface ISome{
    void fly();
}
```

I would like to allow that

```
class A implements ISome {}
```

but block that

```
public interface IHouse extends ISome{
    void fly();
}
```

doing this

```
public final interface ISome{}
```

makes no sense... and will bring a compile error like:

```
Illegal modifier for the interface
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

Supposedly the Java designers didn't think there would ever be an appropriate use case for this: if you don't want an `interface` to be extended then really you ought to declare those functions directly in a concrete `class`.

That said, you *can* achieve this in C++ as in this language an interface is more of a *convention* - consisting of only pure virtual functions, and you can enforce non-extensibility with techniques such as `friend`ship.